# in jni_onLoad TRACEME ERROR

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface

In my `jni_onLoad` I'm calling `ptrace(TRACEME,0,0,0)` but I get:

> error in logcat as avc: denied { ptrace } for scontext=u:r:zygote:s0
>   tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tclass=proces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your android devices, if you don't open selinux ,then it will not cause that problem,when opened selinux,it's will cause that problem.I solve it by updating selinux enfore,if opened selinux, when you `cat /sys/fs/selinux/enfore`, it appears 1,theregfore, if you update 1 to 0, then can solve it,my code is `echo 0>/sys/fs/selinux/enforce`